# How to delete and remove references to a file, that is invisible in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using Xcode, and someone added framework to main folder and I must remove it.

I don't see framework folder inside of main folder, when I am using Xcode.
[image]

But according to Finder, framework file is actually there.
[image]

Xcode seems to have generated references to framework folder, because it didn't compile, after I have deleted MobileSDK using Finder

```
Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'Homebank' from project 'Homebank') Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
```

How to remove framework folder?